# elementary OS Freya 0.3.1 Mouse Problems

Tags: release-freya, mouse

I have installed elementary OS 0.3.1. I notice that I need to press my mouse buttons very hard to make it work. I can move the cursors around the screen smoothly with no problems, but the main problem are the buttons. Somtimes it even happens that the buttons do not work at all. I can move my cursor, use my keyboard, but I can't click on anything no matter how hard I press. It is not a hardware problem, because it didn't happen in Ubuntu or Fedora or Windows. I even tried two different mouses, plugging them in two different ports without any result. How to solve this?

Comment: It is not hardware. Today I have installed elementary OS 0.3.1 and the same is happening to me. It doesn't move untile press hard or in the middle of the pad.

Comment: have had something like this before, but only a temporary problem.  are you on a laptop or desktop?  when this happens on my laptop, simply suspending and re-logging in fixes it. no idea why it happens though.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the drivers (try reinstalling them)

But an OS doesn't care about the "single-click-sensitivity", it only checks if the mouse registers a keypress or not. So its probably a hardware issue.